# Is there a way to print out the contents of a std::list without overloading the << operator?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have something of the form:

```
struct Tree {
    string rule;
    list<Tree*> children;
}
```

I'm trying to print it out from within this for loop.

```
for(list<Tree*>::iterator it=(t->children).begin(); it != (t->children).end(); it++) {
    // print out here
}
```

Comment: where are you overloading the << operator?

Comment: @aakash I'm trying to see if I can print without overloading the << operator.

Comment: Since you want to print recursively, it'd be easiest to define a helper function to do the printing. Otherwise you'll need to employ the usual recurstion-to-iteration techniques, which usually involve some sort of queue.

Comment: @chris: I think the point of the question is how to avoid defining a function while still performing some recursive work.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I missed the recursion. That makes more sense.

Comment: Since all members of `Tree` are public, you can print them directly: `std::cout << (*it)->rule;`. If you want to print all subtrees recursively, you'll probably want to do this in a recursive function (but it doesn't need to be an operator).

Comment: I'm trying to print just the 'rule' field when printing a tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always turn recursion into iteration. Here's with an auxiliary queue:

```
std::deque<Tree *> todo;

todo.push_back(t);

while (!todo.empty())
{
    Tree * p = todo.front();
    todo.pop_front();

    std::cout << p->rule << std::endl;

    todo.insert(todo.end(), p->children.begin(), p->children.end());
}
```

In C++11 this would of course be a `for` loop:

```
for (std::deque<Tree *> todo { { t } }; !todo.empty(); )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting technique. That actually might help me with something I'm doing :p